# Why is a bareword following the concatenation operator a string in Perl?

Tags: perl, bareword

Why does Perl (5.30.3 but also `no feature ':all'`) assume a bareword following the concatenation operator `.` to be a string? For example:

```
use v5.30;   # or: no feature ':all'; 
use strict;
use warnings;
my $k1 = 'a';
my $k2 = 'b';
print STDOUT $k1 . k2 . "\n";
```

prints out `ak2` (`ab` was intended), and raises no exceptions about barewords being not allowed here. This is a bug in my script, though not necessarily in Perl.

According to [`perlglossary`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary#bareword), a bareword is a "word sufficiently ambiguous to be deemed illegal under `use strict 'subs'`." However, since a scalar named `$k2` was defined before `k2`, I'd have thought `k2` to be ambiguous enough.

Curiously, an exception is raised with a second bareword:

```
use v5.30;   # or: no feature ':all';
use strict;
use warnings;
my $k1 = 'a';
my $k2 = 'b';
my $k3 = 'c';
print STDOUT $k1 . k2 . k3  . "\n";
```

And:

```
Bareword "k3" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at mwe.pl line 7.
Execution of mwe.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

`k3` is not allowed, but `k2` is. Why?

Comment: *"prints out ak2"* : With perl 5.34.0 I get compile error *"Bareword "k2" not allowed while "strict subs" in use*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug introduced in 5.28.0 and fixed in 5.32.0.

A newly-added compile-time optimisation of (usually multiple) string concatenations was skipping the bareword check.

Comment: [Demo](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/0f3dc0cc247b6fff7ccf72981c658ef7)